# Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable

Tags: php, laravel-5, automated-tests, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I have to test using dusk and I have this tag for 3 times

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter teammate's email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter teammate's email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter teammate's email">
</div>
```

and I tried these  to run it

```
->type('input[name=email[]]', $userEmail)->type('email[]', $userEmail)->type('input[type=email]', $userEmail)
```

but not working what is the correct one to type the email ??

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Its give me this error (Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable) or this (Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textarea[name='input[name=email[]]']"})

Comment: Where's that `textarea` bit coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The first option doesn't work because of the square brackets. You need to wrap the name in double quotes:

```
->type('input[name="email[]"]', $userEmail)
```

You can also use the second option:

```
->type('email[]', $userEmail)
```

Typing in all three inputs requires a loop:

```
foreach ($browser->elements('input[name="email[]"]') as $element) {
    $element->sendKeys($userEmail);
}
```